# Spock parametrization vs. Scala TableDrivenPropertyChecks

Tags: scala, scalatest

Spock framework contains `@Unroll` annotation which results in showing each 'case' from parametrized test as a separate test. Is something similar possible with ScalaTest?

Answer (score 1):

A code snippet from the internet which worked for me:

```
import org.scalatest.FreeSpec
import org.scalatest._
import org.scalatest.prop.TableDrivenPropertyChecks

class OrderValidationTableDrivenSpec extends FreeSpec 
                                        with TableDrivenPropertyChecks 
                                        with Matchers {

"Order Validation" - {
  "should validate and return false if" - {
    val orders = Table(
      ("statement"                          , "order")
      , ("price is negative"                , Order(quantity = 10, price = -2))
      , ("quantity is negative"             , Order(quantity = -10, price = 2))
      , ("price and quantity are negative"  , Order(quantity = -10, price = -2))
    )

    forAll(orders) {(statement, invalidOrder) =>
      s"$statement" in {
        OrderValidation.validateOrder(invalidOrder) shouldBe false
      }
    }
   }
  }
}
```

Imports and class naming may be different depends on scalatest version.

Answer (score -2):

The closest would be the [table-driven property checks](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/table_driven_property_checks):

```
import org.scalatest.prop.TableDrivenPropertyChecks._

val fractions =
  Table(
    ("n", "d"),  // First tuple defines column names
    (  1,   2),  // Subsequent tuples define the data
    ( -1,   2),
    (  1,  -2),
    ( -1,  -2),
    (  3,   1),
    ( -3,   1),
    ( -3,   0),
    (  3,  -1),
    (  3,  Integer.MIN_VALUE),
    (Integer.MIN_VALUE, 3),
    ( -3,  -1)
  )

import org.scalatest.matchers.ShouldMatchers._

forAll (fractions) { (n: Int, d: Int) =>

  whenever (d != 0 && d != Integer.MIN_VALUE
      && n != Integer.MIN_VALUE) {

    val f = new Fraction(n, d)

    if (n < 0 && d < 0 || n > 0 && d > 0)
      f.numer should be > 0
    else if (n != 0)
      f.numer should be < 0
    else
      f.numer should be === 0

    f.denom should be > 0
  }
}
```

There are other techniques such as ["sharing tests"](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/sharing_tests) and 
more [property-based testing](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/property_based_testing).

Comment: That doesn't help in case of printing every test params from table of cases. You just explained how parametrised tests may be configured.